# tikzpicture in beamer?

Tags: tikz-pgf, beamer, overlays, overlap

I am using

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{Madrid}
\usecolortheme{beaver}
\usepackage{tikz}
```

I am using tikz in order to overlap two pictures:

```
\begin{frame}{Ghost Imaging}
text
\begin{center}      
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node<1> (GIslides) {\includegraphics[width=0.67\linewidth]{image 1}};
\pause
\node<2> (GIslidesPlen)  {\includegraphics[width=0.67\linewidth]{image2}};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{center}
\end{frame}
```

The result is:

[image]

As you can see in the first slide there is not the description at the bottom, how can I add it?

Comment: Removing `\pause` seems to solve the problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are specifying the overlay twice by using `\pause` and `<num>` at the same time, and (as has been pointed out in the comments), once you remove the unnecessary `\pause` the bar at the bottom of the slide is printed as expected:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{Madrid}
\usecolortheme{beaver}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}{Ghost Imaging}
    text
    \begin{center}      
        \begin{tikzpicture}
            \node<1> (GIslides) {\includegraphics[width=0.67\linewidth]{example-image-a}};
        %   \pause
            \node<2> (GIslidesPlen)  {\includegraphics[width=0.67\linewidth]{example-image-b}};
        \end{tikzpicture}
        
    \end{center}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]